# What is the minimum distance from the floor for a 1/2 bath power outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am remodeling our 1/2 bath and about to mount a floating sink/vanity. There is an existing power outlet on the side wall, that is in the way and that is about 10” from the floor (measured to the bottom of the receptacle). Would it be to the code (KY, USA) if I moved the outlet down a bit where it is 6” above floor, just clearing a 5.5” tall baseboard?  This is the only putlet in this bathroom, and its circuit is already GFCI-ed in another bathroom.

Edit: added photo for better illustration of the two options I am considering.[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that if it's not already GFCI, you'll probably have to change it to a GFCI outlet to meet current code. Since you're modifying, I believe that means anything you touch is no longer grandfathered in.

Comment: Is there already an outlet serving that vanity/sink area at countertop level?

Comment: @FreeMan so that circuit is already GFCI-ed in another bathroom. I am thinking of opening up the wall and see, if I have enough slack I will move it toward the front of the cabinet, if not, anyone can comment on the “moving outlet lower” question? Thanks.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, no, there is only one near floor.

Comment: Have you considered making your switching box a 3 gang and putting a receptacle there? You can use the existing j-box as a blank face junction and run new wire up. (It just seems like both low options would be bothersome in use.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I considered it, however, the it’s wired to another hallway outlet. Only way that would work, if I move that box down, put a blank, then fish wires to 3-gang. Too much work, plus we’ve actually NEVER used this receptacle, not once.  If I move it down, then might as well keep it as a receptacle. So that is why I was asking if it can be that low. I know in other locations you can have them in baseboards and even floor. Wasn’t sure if bathroom was okay. I specifically asked about 1/2 bath, as there is no bathtub/shower, just toilet and sink, in case that was a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

A receptacle not serving the basin has no height requirement in a dwelling unit, but...

2017 NEC 210.52(D)Bathrooms. At least one receptacle shall be installed in bathrooms within 3 ft of the outside edge of each basin...In no case ...be located more than 12 in. below the top of the basin.

I don't have record of when this was adopted but it isn't highlighted grey in the codebook, so it has been in there since 2014 at least.

I think it may have been possible if the switches are within 3' that there was a receptacle and switch, the switch fed both the light and fan but somebody removed the receptacle to have space to put a timer on the fan. If it is only one circuit in that switchbox and it feeds receptacles outside of this bathroom it wouldn't meet current code. I don't know what the code said when built but modifications are required to meet current code.